# Can I run Ubuntu only on power cable without battery?

Tags: power-management, battery, 20.04

My Aspire V3-571g laptop is not able to charge the battery while running anymore, so I use it on power cable only without a battery. Now when I boot grub shows up correctly, but then when loading Ubuntu it shuts down immediately. Is there a way I can use my laptop without a battery?

Answer (score 1):

Whether a laptop can function when the battery is removed depends on its hardware. Some laptops can work normally when connected to the power source via the adaptor with the battery removed, and some laptops can't function if the battery is either removed or worn out. If the store where you are shopping for a laptop has floor demonstration models, ask a shop worker to take out the battery and check if it works before you buy it.